# How to process everytime component is visibile?

Tags: reactjs

When the path contains 'tabs/list' then the following component is shown. In that case I want to show a spinner. Currently the spinner is only shown once. When I change route and go back to 'tabs/list' it doesnt spin again.

```
import {IonContent, IonHeader, IonPage, IonTitle, IonToolbar, useIonLoading} from '@ionic/react';
import {useEffect} from "react";


const List: React.FC = () => {
    const [present, dismiss] = useIonLoading();

    useEffect(() => {
        present();
        setInterval(() => {
            dismiss();
        }, 2000)
    },[])

    return (
        <IonPage>
            <IonHeader>
                <IonToolbar>
                    <IonTitle>List</IonTitle>
                </IonToolbar>
            </IonHeader>
            <IonContent fullscreen>
                <IonHeader collapse="condense">
                    <IonToolbar>
                        <IonTitle size="large">Tab 2</IonTitle>
                    </IonToolbar>
                </IonHeader>
            </IonContent>
        </IonPage>
    );
};

export default List;
```

What do I have to change so useEffect is triggered everytime path is 'tabs/list'?

Answer (score 0):

Try to have useEffect in this format with an empty brackets at the end and it will always run when component mounts or whenever component props or state changes :

```
  useEffect(() => {
        present();
        setInterval(() => {
            dismiss();
        }, 2000)
    }, [] )
```

Comment: I just edited my question: The empty brackets are already there. But it is still not working.